# Turn a positive clock edge into a negative pulse to make a 74LS170/670 register file synchronous

Tags: clock, flipflop, edge, register-file

This is a follow-up o [Why did they make the 74x170 (670) register file asychronous, no CLK input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466826/why-did-they-make-the-74x170-670-register-file-asychronous-no-clk-input).

I want to use that "register file" for my project, but I need to make it behave properly as a synchronous D-flip-flop with a proper clock input. Here is the pin-out of the 74LS170:

[image: Pin-out of the 74LS170]

So there is the active-low write enable -Ew (BTW: how do we write formulas here with an over-line and subscript?). This -Ew is active low. As long as -Ew is low the changes on the input D-pins propagate to the output Q-pins. Once -Ew is high, the last state of the D-inputs is latched in the Q-output.

I am not concerned about the -Er output enable, I tie that to low, and the open-collector nature of the 74LS170 and its adaptation to normal TTL is another subject, not relevant here.

What I want is a short negative pulse on -Ew on the rising edge of the clock.

Here is the very straight forward solution I can come up with, but I don't like it. I am looking for something simpler, more nifty.

So what I have here is 2 input lines, -G for the active-low write enable (named G as it is in the 74LS173 D-flip-flop), and the clock CLK; creating the output -Ew to go into the register file chip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52mNt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The CLK goes into an edge detector built with a capacitor in-line and the resistor, to give a quick pulse on the rising edge of CLK. The time constant of about 100 ns should perform OK up to about 1 MHz, and definitely for my slow breadboard prototype. But that pulse is positive, so I need to put it through an inverter to become adapted to the active low sense, and then the OR gate makes sure that -Ew is low only when -G is low on the rising edge of the CLK.

What I don't like about this is that now I need 2 additional chips a 6-way inverter and a 4 x 2-input OR gate, a massive overhead!

I happen to have a spare 5-input NOR gate near this register already (from my zero-detection logic using a 2 x 5-input NOR gate), and I wonder if there might be any way I could use that. But I don't think NOR helps me at all. So the best I can do is bite the bullet and swap that 2 x 5-input NOR gate with a 4 x 1-input OR gate and a 6-way inverter. I need 3 of the OR gates and one inverter for what I did with that 5-input NOR gate, and so I have then 1 OR gate and 1 inverter (plus another 4 spare inverters left over, which I might put to some other use.) That way I only need to add one additional chip to what I already have now. Not too bad actually.

Still, I wish there was an easier way.

For example, how would I build a falling edge detector with a capacitor? If I could build a falling edge detector which would give a quick negative pulse only on the falling edge of -CLK, I could actually save myself the inverter, since I have another way to invert the output from the OR gate for the zero detection by using a 74LS73 instead of a '173 for the zero and carry flags.

**UPDATE** (from the comments and further thinking):

- I don't consider setup time an issue for me, as I am not planning to run high clock frequencies (for now).
- Hold time might be an issue if it is long as compared to the
  propagation time from D to Q. from the data sheet I see '170 setup
  time 15 ns while the '173 is only 3 ns, I guess I'll see how that goes.
- The minimal -Ew pulse is 25 ns per data sheet so my 100 nf * 1 kOhm should be fine.
- Been thinking all night how to adapt the open collector output of the 74LS170 to straight TTL without inverting, and I haven't come up with anything, so I guess that's where the other 4 inverters of the 6 x inverter IC will have to be used for.

Comment: So you want a short active low pulse every time the clock goes high? 74LS670 works with as little as 25ns pulse width, but setup and hold times could be an issue. Please provide a timing diagram with all relevant signals (including what is on the data lines etc) for a typical read/write cycle.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I don't consider setup time an issue for me, as I am not planning to run high clock frequencies (for now). Hold time might be an issue if it is long as compared to the propagation time from D to Q.  from the data sheet I see '170 setup time 15 ns while the '173 is only 3 ns. The minimal -Ew pulse is 25 ns as you said. So, yes, I want a short pulse down from continuous high every time the clock goes high. And I think my design does that, I am just hoping for something that requires fewer gates, like, maybe another trick with capacitors to pulse downward on a falling edge.

Comment: There might be another solution, but without a timing diagram and/or schematic I can't suggest anything with confidence. You need a negative going pulse derived from the clock rising edge, so an inverter is essential. It's only one extra chip, so why sweat it? I bet you will need more before the design is finished (and _then_ you can look at reducing the chip count).

Comment: BTW have you considered using a 74LS670? Then you might not need those other inverters. They seem to be readily available and not expensive.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I made another question about that open-collector issue and people were telling me, and it seems that it is the definition of open collector, that logic 1 is equivalent to output transistor off. So the use of pull up resistors creates a straight, not an inverted output. The biggest issue, the missing clock, isn't solved by the 74LS670.

Comment: Yes, after reading your other question I wondered why you still needed the inverters. So now you have several left over! I bet you will find a use for them... One more thing to consider - if the design works the next thing you will probably want to do is speed it up. Random delayed clock signals with imprecise RC timing will make that harder. You might want to consider running a higher frequency clock and deriving sub-cycle timing from it, like many microprocessors do.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, hi, long time, I'm still at it: "You might want to consider running a higher frequency clock and deriving sub-cycle timing from it" -- that is exactly what I had concluded now. Because the idea to do try any pulse a the rising edge is futile, let alone with a capacitor. I need a 90 degree delayed clock and a 3-way OR gate, or rather derive a low-state 90 degree before the rising edge and then OR that with the !LOAD control for each of those registers.