# How do I make a 74LS170 or 74LS670 register file reliably clock in data on the rising edge?

Tags: register-file, edge-detection

I am getting a little desperate here. I thought I could replace a single 4-bit D-flip-flop register 74LS173 with the 4 x 4-bit register file 74LS170 or 74LS670. But the problem is that it is a level triggered latch, not an edge-triggered register. I absolutely rely on the ability of the register to clock the current state of the inputs on the rising edge, because soon hereafter the new state will appear on the data input lines and I do not want to latch that.

[image]

[image]

So, what I tried were various edge detection circuits. The inverter-and-trick that everyone talks about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDq9Pu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

this just didn't work for me, even if I used a chain of 3 or 5 inverters. I doubt anyone actually had done this for 74LS04 and 74LS08 chips. Maybe a generation earlier with the slower original 7404 and 7408 chips it could be done, but it simply doesn't work for me. If it works for anyone else, I'd love to see it demonstrated on YouTube or at least a scope photograph.

But the capacitor trick does work to generate a nice downward pulse, when my !LOAD control line is held low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKUlmN.png)</sup>

I have one place where this downward pulse on the rising edge of the clock is generated and then I distribute that to the various 74LS670 register chips where, because I don't have room for 74LS32 quad OR gate chips I just build the OR gate with diode-resistor logic.

The !G_w clock setup works, in slow-motion, by using a 100 pF capacitor, not the 22 pF that I'm showing here in the schematics. But my problem is that once the capacitor C1 is beyond the threshold that it works at all, the pulse appears to be already too long so that the register latches in the changed state of the input after the clock edge, not the state right on the clock edge.

So this is a real bummer. Here I show you on the scope how the signal looks at 650 kHz with the 22 pF:

[image]

and this here is what I get if I use the not-and gate trick. It's not the downward spike, I measured the upper line before the inverter, because after the inverter nothing happens at all. At least here we see the slight wiggle as the clock-and-not-clock-gate switches through.

[image]

Looking at the data sheet, I try to figure out what the minimum t_W and t_su(D) times should be, but I cannot find these numbers actually stated.

[image]

And I did consider that perhaps my downward strobe comes a little after the rising clock edge, so I also derived the CLK' through 2 inverters, but I suppose maybe that doesn't delay the clock enough. So perhaps I need to come up with a way to delay the clock just a tad bit longer to make it come up while the strobe is already solid low. How would I delay the clock just enough?

Is there any other trick? Anyone who has done this? I don't want to drag in a 74LS173 in front of that. There's got to be a way how these '670 can be made to work like normal registers!

Answer (score 4):

I use a 74HCT670 in my homebrew 8 bit CPU called SPAM-1

See https://github.com/Johnlon/spam-1 or more specifically see this verilog model of the CPU https://github.com/Johnlon/spam-1/blob/master/verilog/registerFile/syncRegisterFile.v that I have created to simulate the CPU prior to hardware.

I keep project logs here .. https://hackaday.io/project/166922-spam-1-8-bit-cpu

BTW see also this alternative to the 74670 .. https://hackaday.io/project/166922-spam-1-8-bit-cpu/log/181361-playing-with-the-dm85s68-16x4-synchronous-register-file

---

So ....

Concidentally I was actually finishing off the testing of the register file in hardware tonight and came across this post while browsing.

In SPAM-1's case I want to "clock" data into the register file reliably and without reliance on short pulses who's width I'd have to worry about getting just right.

By understanding the timings in my CPU design I was able to implement a register file based on the 74HCT670 that didn't rely on short pulses. I did this by putting a 74HCT574 in front of the data input and by relying on an understanding of the deliberate timing of signals in my CPU.

So the setup I've used is as follows.

An important feature of my CPUI is that the output of the register file feeds into the input of the ALU, and the output of the ALU feeds back into the register file. This presents a further problem for the use of the 74HCT670 because if the write address of the reg file is the same as the read address of the reg file then the reg file is in a "flow through" configuration and this will setup a situation where the updated output of the ALU updates the reg file which then causes the ALU to settle on a new value which then updates the regfile to a new value and so on. So it is essential for me that this loop cannot occur.

To solve this I have put a 74HCT574 flipflop on the data lines in front of the register file. This prevents the cycle I referred to, and I will come back to discuss this flip flop a bit more in a minute.

In my CPU the CPU increments the program counter on the rising edge of the clock, and executes the instruction on the low phase of the clock.

Consider the high phase of the clock to be *fetch/decode* and the low phase of the clock to be *execute*.

During the fetch/decode phase of the clock, directly after the PC increment the control lines begin to settle and the output of the ALU arrives at the 74HCT574 flipflop.
In my case these control lines also include the /ReadEnable of the 74HCT670 regfile and the write address of the regfile. But I gate the /WriteEnable of the regfile with the clock so the /WE only goes low during the "execute" phase.
The control lines settle completely by the end of the fetch/decode phase.

During the execute phase of the clock I want the data to be latched reliably into the selected write address of the register file. So as the clock goes low and we enter the execute phase I trigger the 74HCT574 flipflop clock line to synchronously load the ALU result into that flip flop. I also enable the /WriteEnable of the regfile only during the execute phase so the new value of the flipflop then flows into the selected address in the regfile.

Because the /WriteEnable is composed of a control line gated with the execute phase of the clock then I can be assured that it will not go low until the beginning of the exec phase and only after all the control lines and buses have settled. I can also be assured that the /WriteEnable will go high again before any of the control lines or busses start moving again at the start of the next fetch/decode cycle.

I can be assured that the /WriteEnable goes high early because all the other control lines are driven by control logic that is in turn driven by values retrieved from a ROM. The ROM has a propagation delay of 70ns and the control logic adds another 50ns. So the control lines into the regfile will remain stable for probably 120ns after the end of the execute phase.

This worked out pretty ok for me in the end and if I add another regfile in parallel then the same single front door flip flop will still work fine.

---

In my case I have actually used 4 x 74HCT670 and a single 75HCT574 for my "synchronous reg file" and I've used these chips to build a triple port 4x8bit register file.

In my CPU the register file there is a single 8 bit write port and two read ports.
The two 8 bit read ports feed both 8 bit inputs of the ALU and so with a triple port regfile I can independently select which of the four 8 bit values appears on each of the ALU inputs.

Like some of the other folk have said there is a similar issue with most RAM (and all latches of which the 74HCT670 is merely a complicated one).

In the case of RAM the issues do not include the "flow through" problem I mention above because they are typically single ported devices unlike the 74670. However, if I were to use a dual port RAM then exactly the same problem could occur.

---

The timing in my CPU looks like this ....

[image]

https://github.com/Johnlon/spam-1/blob/master/docs/regfile-timing.json5

---

To achieve a triple port register file with regular flip flops, would have required more chips and and wiring, so the 74HCT670 is a good choice despite the async behaviour.

---

BTW I also agree that the use of the term "register file" is confusing because I'd gotten used to using *register* to mean a synchronous edge triggered thing and *latch* to mean the async level controlled thing.

However, having read a bit more widely I now prefer to use the term flipflop for the sync thing rather than register as flipflop seems to be universally accepted for the sync thing (eg read data sheets).

Comment: Thank you, interesting ideas. The DM85S68 has a severe disadvantage: you can only select one register for both read and write so you can't do a register transfer in a single operation unless you use some other latch trick. Your triple-ported file appears to require multiple clock cycles. None of it is ideal. I have so many of these chips but they seem useless to me.

Comment: The 74670 is perfectly useful for a little register file and by combining a few of them you get a multiport N-bit wide reg file. 
I wrote the above stuff and even did a video on its use in my CPU...  https://youtu.be/acBR3h197ZU

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching this problem from the wrong direction.

Your initial system design calls for edge triggered latches, like the 173 you used successfully. Now you are trying to replace those with level sensitive latches.

An edge triggered latch has the luxury of very simple timing, most have a zero hold time, you can simply string together a bunch of them and get a clean shift-register when supplying them with an identical clock.

It can be possible, sometimes, to force a level sensitive latch to behave like an edge triggered one if you craft a pulse of exactly the right length for it. It should be long enough to meet its minimum pulse width, but short enough to get in and out while data elsewhere in the system has not changed yet. That's a very unreliable process. You might get it to work on one latch, at a fixed temperature and voltage supply. Getting it to work reliably over a temperature range, with a voltage tolerance, and for several parts is a fool's errand.

The way to employ a level sensitive latch reliably is to take control of the data propagation delays in the rest of the system, often by using additional level sensitive latches on the other polarity of the clock. Or use edge triggered latches elsewhere.

Comment: Ha! That's a nice way to say "sorry dude, it can't be done" by blaming me to be "approaching the problem from the wrong direction". The direction is: begin with the stuff you actually have or can get your hands on. I had a question about these "register files" a few months ago, IMO they are simply bad design for not being edge triggered. They shouldn't even have been called "register file", because all they are is latches. The 74LS172 would be a register file, but it's organized as 8 files of 2 bits. And you can't even get them at Mouser or Jameco. Or rather, sometimes we can get the old 74172

Answer (score 2):

Use it as designed :

`GW_n` is active low, so the last stable value before the rising edge is written into the register, as you want to happen with a rising edge triggered clock.

The only externally observable difference from a rising edge triggered device is, if the read address matches the write address, then the read data follows whatever is happening on the input pins during a Write (when `GW_n` is low).

If that causes problems downstream, one solution may be to follow the register output with a transparent latch (e.g.74LS373), to latch the current output during Write cycles.

Comment: That means I can't really use those as registers at all, but perhaps I can use the 12 chips I have here ... disappointingly as nothing other than tiny SRAM. This is so frustrating! I don't know why these stupid 170 was even invented! Well, OK, it was early, but why the 670??? It serves no reasonable purpose! I can get a little SRAM chip instead! And why didn't they further develop the 74172, nobody has the LS version of it!

Comment: No, it's a perfectly fine part (though I haven't used it since about 1986). You just have expectations other than it was designed to meet. Incidentally almost all SRAMs of its era have similar timings : perhaps you have only used the relatively new "synchronous SRAM" parts?

Comment: SRAM is one thing. A "register file" is another. Calling it a "register file" is false advertisement in my view. SRAM was invented in 1963. So, it's not that when this chip came out in 1970 that it could not have been called a "4 x 4 bit dual port latch" or something. And again, the '172 deserves the name, but somehow was abandoned.